# Das ist genau (es/das), was ich gebraucht habe

Tags: colloquial

Wird *es* oder *das* in den folgenden Sätzen gebraucht? Oder gar nichts?

> Sie muss **(es/das)** gemocht haben, was ich ihr gesagt habe.

> Das ist aber nicht **(es/das)**, wovon ich geredet habe.

> Das ist genau **(es/das)**, was ich gebraucht habe.

Answer (score 1):

Entweder "das", oder gar nichts.

> Sie muss (es) gemocht haben, dass ich ihr schmeichelte.

Da würde ein "es" gehen, oder dort:

> Es ist aber nicht das, wovon ich geredet habe.

sowie:

> Es ist genau (das), was ich gebraucht habe.